# How do I edit Tags (Topics) for many contacts at once?

Tags: data-loader, topics

How do I edit Tags (Topics) for many contacts at once?

We use Topics (which we renamed to "tags") to keep track of the events where we met our contacts and leads. Say I add 100 new leads to Salesforce in bulk (because they all attended the same event). How do I tag them all at the same time?

I know it's possible to edit up to 200 records at a time in list/table view so long as you filter by record type. I have that down pat. But I can't select "topics" or "tags" as a field (column) to be displayed. I can't do this for contacts, nor can I do this for leads.

I know it's possible to use campaigns for this purpose (since you can filter leads and contacts by which campaigns they are a part of). But that's a poor solution because campaigns are clumsy in comparison to tags/topics when looking at individual contact records.

I've found a few postings that suggest that this feature has been one of the most requested features from the Salesforce community for many many years.

Is it possible using the data-loader?

or is it possible using a 3rd party app from the salesforce app ecosystem?

Or is there something I'm missing?